# USB powered sump pump

Tags: usb

I have a USB powered sump pump plugged into my raspberry pi 4. Is there a way to program the turn off and on by including it in my program?

Comment: HI @user111033, Welcome.  Ah, let me see.  (1) I am a pump hobbyist. I have  100+  hours playing with AC220V and DC12V/5V pumps, solenoids, and relays etc.  (2) I am happy to try helping out. Please let me have the web link to you pump.  (3) BTW, I have never heard of the name "sump pump", so I googled and learnt that it for pumping water in the basement.  I have never seen any basement in my city (I guess only 0.1% citizens in my city have basements). (4) However, 99.9% have rooftops.  I have a rooftop garden and I am playing with pumps, using Rpi3B+ and Rpi4B python programs.  Cheers.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07RP52SZJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: A sump pump is a submerged pump to pump water out of a container

Comment: HI @user111033, Oh my goodness, your pump is mini/micro submersible, usually for mini fish tanks. 
Amazon USB Mini/Micro Submersible Motor Pump Water Pumps DC 3/5V 120L/H (1.6 inch Vertical with USB, White) - US$7
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07RP52SZJ/ I do have a couple of those.  I often use 12V/24V DC pumps, or sometimes 220VAC ones.  Low voltage < 5V is for toys and loses my face.  You need to tell me if you are using your basement as a big fish tank, or planting vegetable, and the flow rate, say, how many liters per hour you guess/estimate.

Comment: Ah I read you sump pump definition a bit late.  So you are not using it in the basement.  In that case, you might like to read my old posts to get a rough idea what I have been playng with my pumps: (1) https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?_u=f3thdsb9af2&id=36993226670
(2) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&p=1381664&hilit=12V+DC+pump#p1381664
(3) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=231740&p=1420365&hilit=12V+DC+pump#p1419088
(4) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=231541&p=1418979&hilit=12V+DC+pump#p1418979. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, I am also growing microgreens in my rooftop garden, and using moisture sensors to check out if my plants are thirsty: (1) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=233311#p1429200
(2) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=233311#p1428409.

Comment: Actually my city is trying hard to become a smart city, catching up the other neighbouring smarter city SG, which I think is a couple of years ahead.  So I am adding more and more smart things (eg weight sensor to monitor how my soy beans are putting on weight day by day, under different conditions of LED lighting, etc etc)  to my smart garden, in order not to lose too much face! :) (1) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=219744&p=1381255&hilit=garden#p1381255.